# i dont know why i get error list index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
def longest_run(L):
   inc = []
   num = 0    
   count = 0    
   index = 1    
   while count < len(L)+1:

       if L[num] >= L[index]:
           inc.append(L[index])
       num +=1
       index +=1        
       count += 1

   print (inc)
L = [10, 4, 3, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 2]
```

when take my code I got a error

```
if L[num] > L[index]:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I dont know why my index would be out of range
for example  if num = 2 therefor index = 3
not out of range 
Please help me

Comment: Change `count < len(L) + 1` to `count < len(L) -1` because python indexes from 0, not 1, *and* you are comparing elements of the list with the *next* element in the list.

Comment: You are looping 11 times when you have to loop only 9 times. Because in the 9th loop you have compared the 9th and the 10th element. The 10th loop is trying to compare 10th and the 11th element which doesn't exists in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because of:
    len(L)+1

add `print num, index, count` 
before `print(inc)` and you will solve it